# How to adjust the font size of bera sans?

Tags: fontsize, sans-serif

I am using the Utopia font in my document, and it works perfectly well. As I want to put chemical formulas in sans-serif font, I was now looking for a suitable sans serif font to match the Utopia font.

I found that bera sans fits in an Utopia text very well. However, its letters are just a bit too small in size. It should be possible to change the font size of bera sans by using `\usepackage[scaled=1.1]{berasans}`. Unfortunately, this option does not seem to do anything in my document.

This MWE shows that the bera-sans font is just a bit too small, despite the `scaled` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=1.1]{berasans}

\begin{document}
This is a nice text \textsf{in sans serif}: S\textsf{S}, M\textsf{M}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Cabin` also matches well `utopia`, and has small caps in regular, boldface, italic and italic boldface. You should check if it requires scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It really looks quite nice. I'll consider using it instead. Option `scaled=0.92` seems to be a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `sfscaled=false` option to `mathdesign`. The appropriate scaling in fact seems to be `.90`:  If you are using a mono font as well in your document you may also want to add `ttscaled=false` also.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[adobe-utopia,sfscaled=false]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{berasans}

\begin{document}
This is a nice text \textsf{in sans serif}: S\textsf{S}, M\textsf{M}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]